# Appending to an existing JSON file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, discord

I'm working on a discord bot right now that reads responses off of a JSON file. The basic format is as follows:

```
  "matt":
  {
     "insults" : ["test 1", 
                  "test 2", 
                  "test 3", 
                  "test 4"
                 ]
  },
```

I'm currently working on a function that allows a user to use the `!addInsult` command, followed by a string, which will then append onto the existing array.

My desired workflow is as such:

User types in the following: `!addInsult test 5`. This would then modify the JSON object of `insults` under `matt` to the following:

```
  "matt":
  {
     "insults" : ["test 1", 
                  "test 2", 
                  "test 3", 
                  "test 4",
                  "test 5"
                 ]
  },
```

Doing this will allow me to let my friends add data to my bot without needing me to manually edit the JSON every time we want something new.

What would the best way of going about this be? I've looked into this thing called push, but I don't really understand how that works.

This is what I have so far. I think I'm going in the right direction, but I'm not sure:

The following is established at the beginning of the script:

```
// contains the insults
var insults = require('./insults.json');

// get the insults from the json file specific to user
var insultsString = JSON.stringify(insults);
var json = JSON.parse(insultsString);
```

And here is the function that will be doing appending:

```
// command that allows users to add to the pool of insults
function addInsultCommand(args, receivedMessage)
{
  // create an object that contains the information for the json file
  json["bot"].push(["test"]);

  receivedMessage.channel.send(json.matt.insults[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so there is a misconception here; JS does not write to files.

You're using webpack, which let's you `require` the .json using a webpack loader, but this will ONLY work when using the dev server. This will not work when distributing your code, because the .json will will be encoded into your output bundle.

.js can not write a file for you ( except locally ), so what you need to do is two fold:

1) Download the .json from the webserver, without using a webpack loader.

2) modify the JSON data in memory

3) upload the JSON data to the web server for it to write the file for you.

In addition to this, I can not follow your example code. you reference `receivedMessage.channel.send`, but I do not see where this is defined. Is this some kind of discord integration? You may need to re-state your question along with a minimal proof of the issue with reproducible test code.

Comment: If you want, I can post the entirety of the code. And yes, `receivedMessage.channel.send` is a discord specific thing.This code is being hosted on Gltich, which creates an express server for me online.

Comment: yes that would help, maybe I can point out the disconnect. as it is, I don't see how `json["bot"].push(["test"]);` is connected to `json.matt.insults`

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify will turn a javascript object into a JSON object.  JSON.parse will do the opposite(turn a JSON object into a Javascript object).  Assuming insults.json is a json object, you do not need to convert it into a string.  You can just do JSON.parse(insults) to convert it into a javascript object.

I am not sure what you were intending to do with the args variable in addInsultCommand but I am going to ignore for now and give you some steps to follow below.

1) Turn JSON object(insults) into JS object

2) create a function that takes a JS object and a receivedMessage(the insult to add) and assigns it to the correct place in the JS object.

3) convert the JS object into JSON(using JSON.stringify) and replace the contents of insults.json with the the updated value.